# How do I fetch the users of a Subscriber List with Attributes?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I have a very large list of Subscribers, and a much more limited specific Distribution List (say, 1000-10000 subscribers in the list).  I need to pull and process (hopefully, via FuelSDK) the subscribers in the list, complete with all Attributes.

Is there any way to do this efficiently?  Can I get `FuelSDK::List::Subscriber.new` to return Attribute values?  Alternatively, can I get `FuelSDK::Subscriber.new` to filter by a `ListID`?  Is there another way?